# C - exec to execute command with arguments?

Tags: c, command, exec

I am trying to run a simple C program that executes a command with some arguments:

> `ls -l -a -i`

I have searched for info about the `exec` family, but don't understand all the different `exec` calls and which one to use.

My program is:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    const char *cmd = "ls";
    const char *args[3];
    args[0] = "-l";
    args[1] = "-a";
    args[2] = "-i";

    execv(cmd, args); /* this line does not work */

    return 0;
}
```

I thought `execv` is called with:

- `char *cmd` as the command
- `char *args[]` as the arguments

But I'm getting errors with all different combinations and attempts.

Comment: from [man execv()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv): "**The list of arguments must be terminated by a NULL pointer,**" (and what @mch said, but that's likely to "only" cause a compiler warning ... take it seriously anyways)

Comment: Also think back to how you handle arguments yourself, what is `argv[0]`? The `args` array you pass is what becomes the `argv` array in that program.

Comment: And *read the manual page*, the `cmd` to `execv` is the *path* to the program to execute. If you want to execute a program in the `$PATH` use `execvp`. And don't forget that `exec` *replaces* your running program.

Comment: `char *args[] = { "ls", "-l", "-a", "-i", 0 }; execv("/bin/ls", args);`

Answer (score 1):

here you are a piece of code that works and you should use as reference to succeed in your task :

```
char* arr[] = {"ls", "-l", "-a", "-i", NULL};

execv("/bin/ls", arr);
```

Comment: please pay attention to format code as such. Easiest method is to mark all the code and hit `ctrl + k` -- fixed it for you ;)